# Empty body element with exact A4 landscape dimension is printed on 2 pages

Tags: html, css, printing

Demo:

```js
print()
```

```css
@page {
    size: A4 landscape;
    margin: 0;
}
html, body {
    margin: 0;                
}
html {
    background: cyan;
}
body {
    width: 297mm;
    height: 210mm;                
    background: red;
}
```

The dimensions for `A4 landscape` are correct, but the print overflows to the second page. These happens in Win 10 Chrome 63, FF 52 and Edge 41.

[image]

> When I use the portrait dimensions and print A4 Portrait, then only one page is printed as expected, without any overflow.

Does anybody have any clues to this issue? Does it occur on every platform?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Are you using a windows pc?
Check the paddings that are set by default (by windows).
Because on my linux machine its just 1 page.

Comment: @zeropublix, yes, its win10 machine. Thank you for the feedback regarding linux.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> used `body {margin-top: -1px }`

```js
print()
```

```css
@page {
    size: A4 landscape;
    margin: 0;
}
html, body {
    margin: 0;      
}
html {
    background: cyan;
}
body {
    width: 297mm;
    height: 210mm;     
    background: red;
    margin-top: -1px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Farhad. But it doesn't fix the overfow for me. I still see 2 pages. I have tested also on several pc _(win10)_ machines and everywhere 2 pages are printed.

Comment: Hi Farhad, thanks, it really fixes the 2-page-print, but it doesn't prevent the overflow. With the workaround we just cut the page from the top. Similar would also the `body{ position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0;}` do, but from the bottom. With `body { display: border-box; border: 1px solid green }` the top border is not visible any more. Anyway, this is so far, the best, but hacky, workaround for the issue. I will look further for a solution and explaination of the overflow. If I find nothing, I would accept this solution, thank you once again.

Comment: If you mind, I have edited the post, to remove the page-break rule, as it has no influence on the behaviour. Only margin-top is matter. Also only for `body` not `html, body`, to prevent double margin, as it applies then for html and also body.

Answer (score 0):

refer this solution:
html:

```
<div class="book">
    <div class="page">
        <div class="subpage">Page 1</div>    
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
 body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #FAFAFA;
    font: 12pt "Tahoma";
}
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}
.page {
    /*width: 210mm;
    min-height: 297mm;*/
    width:297mm;
    min-height:210mm;
    padding: 20mm;
    margin: 10mm auto;
    border: 1px #D3D3D3 solid;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: white;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
.subpage {
    padding: 1cm;
    border: 5px red solid;
    height: 257mm;
    outline: 2cm #FFEAEA solid;
}

@page {
    size: A4;
    margin: 0;
}
@media print {
    html, body {
        width: 210mm;
        height: 297mm;        
    }
    .page {
        margin: 0;
        border: initial;
        border-radius: initial;
        width: initial;
        min-height: initial;
        box-shadow: initial;
        background: initial;
        page-break-after: always;
    }
}
```

js:

```
window.print();
```

Comment: Thanks Kumar, I have already seen such an example on stackoverflow, but as I have mentioned, the portrait A4 dimensions are printed, as expected, on 1 page, the overflow occures only with A4 landscape dimensions. When I change your sample for landscape, I see 2 pages again.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
body {
    margin-top: -1px;
}
```

It might not work but this is my best guess.